# Нужна ли блокировка файла при чтении/записи?

Tags: файлы, php

Здравствуйте. При открытии файла для редактирования (fopen,fwrite, fclose), необходимо блокировать доступ к файлу (flock).

Нужно ли блокировать доступ, если я использую функцию file_put_contents или даже copy() c заменой существующего?

Comment: @Deus, необходимость *любых блокировок* зависит только от логики приложения.

Comment: @avp, не согласен. В тооолстых учебника написано, что в то время, когда файлом пользуется 100000 человек, есть вероятность совпадения времени записи и считывания файла разными источниками. От нечего делать я программирую CMS, которая работает не с БД, а с файлами. Так вот, я и интересуюсь, нужно ли блокировать некоторый файл .html при вызове функции file_put_content. Вдруг в это же время этот файл кому-то загружается?

Comment: @Deus, винчестер не может одновременно читать и писать, обгоняя чтение. Я думаю, что возможность "плохого чтения" возможна разве что при плохом винче и плохой операционке.

Comment: @Fike, к серверу за одну секунду могут обратиться 100 000 пользователей. И в тот миг, когда я делаю fwrite(), если вероятность, что именно в этот миг кто-то заливает этот файл html себе в браузер. Конфликт чтения/записи. Об этом говориться в любой литературе по файлам. Я спросил поэтому, касается ли это и функции file_put_contents()?

Comment: @Deus, ох, хотите блокировать - блокируйте. Вордпресс по секунде грузится и ничего, счастливые юзеры только рады еще десятка с два тормозных плагинов накидать. У вас никогда не будет столько пользователей и вы никогда не сможете этот конфликт (записи-чтения) разрешить, потому что приложение надо обновлять время от времени, а файлы инклюдятся не синхронно. Но пользователи обычно подходят с другой стороны и берут БД, если им _действительно_ нужно разрешить проблемы такого планы (и с удивлением обнаруживают, что БД занимается именно записью данных в файл). cont->

Comment: Под проблемой записью-чтения обычно имеется в виду все-таки расчет, в котором исходное значение уже устаревает к концу расчета. Но я не поленился вбить это в гугл, и на первой странице - вы не поверите - нашел вот это: http://hashcode.ru/questions/146959/php-file_put_contents-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82

Comment: @Fike, спасибо, но ответа нет. Я сам использую БД для проектов. Просто, как и тот пользователь из вашей ссылки, решил поюзать именно файлы...

Comment: @Deus эта задача не имеет практического применения. Если десятки тысяч стучатся в регулярно обновляемый файл, значит вы что-то делаете не так. Достаточно хотя бы читать его в кэш раз в пятнадцать минут, чтобы избежать проблемы одновременной записи и чтения. Не забыв сделать защиту от dogpile-эффекта, конечно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Deus](/users/2665/deus)](/users/2665/deus), в Вашем случае (одновременная работа многих независимых запросов), конечно-же -- ДА, нужно.

Перед чтением -- совместная блокировка (LOCK_SH), а перед записью -- эксклюзивная (LOCK_EX).

Детали, например, в [flock — Портируемая консультативная блокировка файлов](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.flock.php).

Кстати, обратите внимание, что `flock()` никак не влияет на возможность/невозможность выполнения fopen/fread/fwrite и т.п. Т.е. `flock` в одном процессе влияет на приостановку другого процесса именно на вызове `flock` в нем. (по крайней мере в *nix-ах).

Comment: @avp, че-то я подумал, а вдруг в функцию file_put_content() внесена автоматическая процедура блокировки. Ну, спасибо. Я думаю, информация пригодится.

Comment: @Deus, боюсь при использовании file_get_contents/file_put_contents у Вас возникнут некоторые проблемы с блокировками. 

file_put_contents это надо как-то выяснить) может открывать файл на запись, сразу урезая его до нулевой длины. Тут Вас никакой встроенный в эту функцию LOCK_EX не спасет от потери данных в не до конца прочитанном (хотя и заблокированном в другом процессе) файле.

Да и вообще, обратите внимание, что эти функции получают в аргументах **имя файла**, а в flock в любом случае используется handle, а не имя.

Answer (score 2):

> @avp, че-то я подумал, а вдруг в функцию file_put_content() внесена >автоматическая процедура блокировки. Ну, спасибо. Я думаю, информация пригодится.

Автоматической блокировки нету. Как написано в документации:

> Функция идентична последовательным успешным вызовам функций fopen(), fwrite() и fclose().

А по поводу как блокировать при использовании file_put_contents() тоже в доке написано, доступны флаги.

пример из документации:

```
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

> может открывать файл на запись, сразу урезая его до нулевой длины.

Опять таки, доступен флаг:

**FILE_APPEND**  - Если файл ***filename*** уже существует, данные будут дописаны в конец файла вместо того, чтобы его перезаписать.